# How to use AWS CreateLaunchConfigurationResponse in .NET

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am writing my first ever code for AWS.
I have downloaded the AWS .NET SDK.

I need to programmatically Create/Launch/Terminate an EC2 instance.

I was able to write the following lines of code, but have no idea what do from here:

```
public static Boolean LaunchInstance()
{

    NameValueCollection appConfig = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

    AmazonAutoScaling autoscaling = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonAutoScalingClient(
        appConfig["AWSAccessKey"],
        appConfig["AWSSecretKey"]
        );

    CreateLaunchConfigurationResponse ccResponse = autoscaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration(new CreateLaunchConfigurationRequest());


    return true;

}
```

I am stuck because I can't understand how to use the CreateLaunchConfigurationResponse and can't find any example on the internet.
Do you have any example how to use this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going crazy all day, I was able to create/launch an instance with this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Amazon;
using Amazon.EC2;
using Amazon.EC2.Model;
using Amazon.AutoScaling;
using Amazon.AutoScaling.Model;


namespace HG.AWS
{
    public class AutoScale
    {
        public static Boolean LaunchInstance()
        {


            AmazonEC2Config EC2Config = new AmazonEC2Config()
            .WithServiceURL("https://ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com");


            NameValueCollection appConfig = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;


            AmazonEC2 ec2 = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonEC2Client(
                appConfig["AWSAccessKey"], 
                appConfig["AWSSecretKey"],
                EC2Config);

            try
            {

                RunInstancesRequest EC2R = new RunInstancesRequest();
                EC2R.ImageId = "ami-885b6bfc";
                EC2R.InstanceType = "m1.large";
                EC2R.MaxCount = 1;
                EC2R.MinCount = 1;
                RunInstancesResponse r = ec2.RunInstances(EC2R);
```